# How to refer to a specific object in a list, not all the objects that are the same value but different?

Tags: python

For example, `mylist = [0,1,2,0]`
I want `mylist[0] == mylist[-1]` to output `False` as it is a different instance of 0, but it is true because they are both zeroes. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: 0 is not a class. There is no such statement as "different instances of 0". And they are even the same object according to Python's small integer pool optimization.

Comment: It sounds like you want to compare indexes, not values at those indexes.

Comment: You can use `is` to check whether it is the same object; but in this case, both occurrences of `0` **actually are** the same object. Please see the linked duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

In your case the `mylist[0]` and `mylist[-1]` are not only equal but also the same (same object in memory)

```
>>> mylist = [0,1,2,0]
>>> mylist[0] == mylist[-1]
True
>>> mylist[0] is mylist[-1]
True
>>> id(mylist[0])
140736735811200
>>> id(mylist[-1])
140736735811200
>>>
```

You should not receive a `False`.

You can read these articles to better understand this topic:
https://realpython.com/python-is-identity-vs-equality/, https://anvil.works/articles/pointers-in-my-python-1

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to compare values and their indexes.

```
mylist = [0,1,2,3,0]
if mylist[0] == mylist[-1] and mylist.index(mylist[0]) == mylist.index(mylist[-1]):
    print(“True”)
else:
    print(“False”)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to compare indexes and not the values at those indexes.

This code does this by ignoring the container:

```py
def compare(container, index1, index2):
    return index1 == index2

mylist = [0,1,2,0]
print(compare(mylist, 0, -1))
```

Output:

`False`